# Changing date formats with python from one to another

Tags: python, datetime

I have a series of tables that I am using to create a map in ArcGIS desktop. In the attribute table there is a date column in the format "19950129000000" and I would like to convert this format to something more meaningful such as "29/1/1995". The column says it is in a string format, but the metadata says it is in a date format.

I have done something similar before but I am having trouble getting it to work.

I've tried: 
def dtConversion(date):
  from datetime import datetime
  od = datetime.strptime(date, "YYYYMMddhhmmss")
  nd = datetime.strftime(od, "%d/%m/%Y")
  return nd

**esri_field_calculator_splitter**
dtConversion(!CMPLDT!)

Comment: Have you seen the `strptime` documentation? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior . I ask because your `strptime` format string isn't valid.

Comment: Can you post what happened when you tried `def dtConversion(date):` so that others can reproduce your result?

Comment: There was no result, I just would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

datetime.strptime('19950129000000', "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

Comment: Thank you so much! I was wondering if I would need to use "%" before each one. I really appreciate the help @Mohit Rustagi